# How to run php files on Phone Gap?

Tags: php, ajax, mobile, cordova

I need to run some php files with my application, I uploaded them to my website. I have read an article here, I did same thing for my files but my php file is working with ajax, so I couldnt run it. I tried all possible ways but I am still mistaken.

search.html creates a link via js and passes this link to get_data.php, and shows results in the same page with `results` tag.

search.html

```
function abc(target_url) {


    target_url = target_url||(generate_url()||"http://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?");
    ajax = window.XMLHttpRequest?(new XMLHttpRequest()):(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp"));
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if(ajax.readyState===4) {
        html_data = ajax.responseText;
        //Do stuff with it like parsing, etc
        //alert(html_data);
        window.loading.style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html_data ||"We're sorry";
      }
    };
    ajax.open("GET", "./get_data.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(target_url), true);
    ajax.send(null);
    window.loading.style.visibility="visible";


  }
```

This is get_data.php

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url = $_REQUEST["url"];
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
$gokhan='arik';
#$anchors = array_diff($html->find('table[class=resultsTable] a'), $html->find('td[class=addbutton] a'));
$h2 = $html->find('table[class=resultsTable] h2');
$ipeds = $html->find('p[class=ipeds hoverID]');

foreach($html->find('div[id=ctl00_cphCollegeNavBody_ucResultsMain_divMsg]') as $nOfResults){
            echo "<b>".strip_tags($nOfResults)."</b>";
        }
$loca = $html->find('table[class=itables] tbody tr td[class=pbe]');


for($i=0;$i<count($h2);$i++) {

   if(strip_tags($h2[$i])=="")    continue;
    #echo strip_tags(strtr($ipeds[$i], array("&nbsp;"=>" ")));
    $iped = explode(" ", strip_tags(strtr($ipeds[$i], array("&nbsp;"=>" "))));


    echo "<li data-theme='c' class='ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c'>
            <div class='ui-btn-inner ui-li'>
                <div class='ui-btn-text'>

                    <a href='search2.php?id=".$iped[2]."' class='ui-link-inherit'><h3 class='ui-li-heading'>".strip_tags($h2[$i])."</h3><p class='ui-li-desc'>".strip_tags(strtr($loca[$i], array('</h2>'=>'</h2> ')))."</p></a>
                </div>
                <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow'/>
            </div>
          </li> 
          ";


}
```

?>

Comment: I don't think `PhoneGap` allows you to run PHP on a phone... You'll need to host the PHP on your own server and set up [HTTP_Access_control](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control), so that XHR requests can be made to it from your PhoneGap app.

Comment: That's what I said. You can not run PHP on the phone, my php files on the server. I have trouble to connect them.

On another post it says to use something like this. but it is not working.

`$('#content').load('http://www.example.com/test.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax (the method you are attempting) is the method I would suggest. You are attempting to perform an ajax request without using a framework, if you are not using a framework anywheres else in the site I do think this is a good idea to reduce site load time. But you have some funny things going on in the way you tried to implement ajax.

If you are not going to use some a framework I'd suggest something like http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_callback

I notice in your comment you mentioned

> $('#content').load('http://www.example.com/test.php');

this is referring to the use of jQuery to load content into your page. Looking at the example code you provided above I do not see where you actually imported jQuery. First import [jQuery](http://jquery.com) then try using that code. Also, I would suggest using $.ajax({}) instead of $("#content").load("url");

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://www.example.com/test.php",
   success: function(x){
      $("#results").html(x);
   }
});
```

For more information about using the jQuery framework to do ajax request visit http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/